# Android Layout question

Tags: android, layout

My app has 5 different relative layouts that it can switch between by using a set of buttons that is at the bottom of the screen. 3 of the layouts contain only TextViews and ImageViews. The other 2 both have a ListView in them. On the 2 views that contain lists when the soft keyboard appears the buttons that are along the bottom move up to on top of the soft keyboard. But on the other 3 views the buttons get hidden by the keyboard. The buttons all have the attribute android:alignParentBottom="true" does anyone know why they'd be behaving differently when one of these two are the active layout at the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that happening if you have `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in your manifest. The `ListView` widgets are resizable, and `TextView/ImageView` widgets are not.

Comment: Although I did not have android:windowSoftInputMode set in my manifest it chose "adjustResize" by default because of the list views. I set put android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in my manifest to force it to cover it up even though there is a list view and this worked fine.